# Ms-Access convert datetime to seconds since epoch

Tags: datetime, ms-access, time

In my Ms-Access database, I have an original set of data in a table that I then use `Make Table` to create another table where data is formatted nicely. The issue is, some of the data is formatted as a number or short text, `2020-01-01` or `20200101`. How can I (for either of those formats) create another field in the table where it converts `2020-01-01` to `1577797200` or `20200101` to `1577797200` (local time), for GMT it would be `1577836800`. But I need this format to carry through every record. This needs to use the original set of data to make another table from it. How is this possible?

Comment: Convert the number 20200101 to string with `Format([field], "####-##-##")`. DateDiff will cast the string into a date value. I tested the function as shown in above-referenced link and it returns value of 1577836800. Are you saying these two formats are mixed in same field? Use IIf() expression.

Comment: Worked + the link you sent did too, thanks.